# Movie about a man who is able to send messages using his brain like a fax machine

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

This is what I am able to remember from the movie:

- The man sacrificed his childhood memories to gain this power.
- His ability allows him to be used as a way of sending pictures from his brain to another, by way of fax machine.
- The movie mentioned a woman who died in 2015. And a character mentioned how she died five years ago.
- There's a woman who is a "robot" or something akin to that.
- The movie ends with him regaining his childhood memories.
- The aesthetic reminds me of *Blade Runner*.

I'm sorry if this is very vague. I watched this once on TV, back when I was a child.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know when you were a child, so please tell us approximately what year this was.  It would also be useful to know where you saw this and what language it was in.

Answer (score 16):

Sounds like ***[Johnny Mnemonic](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113481/)*** (1995).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Mnemonic_(film)):

> *Johnny Mnemonic* is a 1995 cyberpunk film directed by Robert Longo in his directorial debut. The film stars Keanu Reeves and Dolph Lundgren. The film is based on the story of the same name by William Gibson. Keanu Reeves plays the title character, a man with a cybernetic brain implant designed to store information. The film portrays Gibson's dystopian view of the future with the world dominated by megacorporations and with strong East Asian influences.

> **In 2021**, society is driven by a virtual Internet, which has created a degenerate effect called "nerve attenuation syndrome" or NAS. Megacorporations control much of the world, intensifying the class hostility already created by NAS.
>
> **Johnny is a "mnemonic courier" who discreetly transports sensitive data for corporations in a storage device implanted in his brain at the cost of his childhood memories.**
>
> [...]
>
> Johnny starts witnessing brief images of **a female projection of an artificial intelligence (AI) who attempts to aid Johnny,** but he dismisses her.
>
> [...]
>
> aided by the female AI, **Johnny is able to decrypt the data and at the same time recover his childhood memories.**

Comment: Oh yes it's seem like this is the movie. thank you !.

Comment: If you believe this is the correct answer, click on the "accept" button under the vote count for the answer.

Comment: I *love* "I can carry 80 gigs of data in my head" (and the Chicago-like font)